# Composite Line and Bar chart

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Based on Gordon's suggestion in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503044/dc-js-composite-bar-chart-line-chart), I am creating a new question. I am using a composite bar and line chart; bar chart for displaying the actual values and line chart to highlight the date filters (to be included later) specific to the filter duration (between the start and and the end times).

I have 2 requirements:

1. I want the line chart to get to 1 exactly for the filter duration and drop to 0 thereafter.
2. I have 2 filter dates mentioned in the example, but only the one that coincides with the chart value gets plotted. I want the other filter to be plotted as well for the specific duration irrespective of the chart value.

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ad2Lnmc9/13/)

```js
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

            var chart = dc.barChart("#test");
            var experiments = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("pre#data").text());
            experiments.forEach(function (x) {
                //console.log('dt: ' + parseDate(x.DT));
                x.DT = parseDate(x.DT);
                //x.DT = +x.DT;
                //console.log('pt: ' + x.Points);
                x.Points = +x.Points;
            });

            var minDate = new Date(2017, 0, 1, 5, 40, 35, 0);
            var maxDate = new Date(2017, 0, 10, 7, 28, 47, 0);

            var ndx = crossfilter(experiments),
   Dim = ndx.dimension(function (d) { return d.DT; }),
   Group = Dim.group().reduceSum(function (d) { return d.Points; });

            compChart = dc.compositeChart("#test1")

            subchart1 = dc.barChart(compChart)
                           .dimension(Dim)
                           .group(Group)
                           //.centerBar(true)
                           .gap(30)
                           .brushOn(true)
                           //.elasticX(true)
                           .elasticY(true)
                           .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
                           .xUnits(d3.time.days)
                           
            subchart2 = dc.lineChart(compChart)                            
                            .group(Group)
                            .colors('red')
                            .renderArea(false)
                            .interpolate('step')
                            .xUnits(d3.time.minutes)
                            .useRightYAxis(true)
                            .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]))
                            .renderDataPoints(true)                            
                            .valueAccessor(function (d) {
                            
            //filter 1
                        var fStart = new Date(2017, 0, 3, 10, 00, 00, 00);
                        var fEnd = new Date(2017, 0, 3, 11, 00, 00, 00);
                        
                        //filter 2
                        var fStart1 = new Date(2017, 0, 8, 14, 30, 00, 00);
                        var fEnd1 = new Date(2017, 0, 8, 17, 45, 00, 00);

                                filterDate = new Date(d.key);

                                console.log('fd :' + filterDate);

                                if (filterDate.getTime() >= fStart.getTime() && filterDate.getTime() <= fEnd.getTime()) {
                                    console.log('inf1');
                                    return 1;
                                }
                                if (filterDate.getTime() >= fStart1.getTime() && filterDate.getTime() <= fEnd1.getTime()) {
                                    console.log('inf2');
                                    return 1;
                                }
                                else {
                                    return 0;
                                }
                            })

            compChart
                 .width(500)
                 .height(300)
                 .margins({top: 5, right: 50, bottom: 20, left: 50})
                 .dimension(Dim)
                 .x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
                 .xUnits(d3.time.days)
                 .elasticY(true)               
                 .rightY(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 1]))                                                    
                 .transitionDuration(100)                  
                 .compose([subchart1, subchart2])

            compChart.render();
```

```html
<div id="test1">
</div>

<pre id="data" style="display: none">
DT,Points
2017-01-01 05:40:35,12
2017-01-02 08:20:12,74
2017-01-03 06:30:06,9
2017-01-04 05:40:53,57
2017-01-05 22:15:19,28
2017-01-06 14:35:41,36
2017-01-07 10:50:23,64
2017-01-08 16:18:02,93
2017-01-09 20:45:36,81
2017-01-10 07:28:47,25
</pre>
```

Thanks,

Arun

Comment: I'm unable to parse your second point - that's pretty convoluted. Are you just looking for a way to outline the filter area? It seems like it might be easier just to style the brush with a border on three sides rather than try to generate new data based on it?